# This is in C # with TexBox and RichTexBox

Tags: c#

I have a task. I have to write something in TexBox and it must go to a RichTexBox.

I understand how it should be, but I don't know how to do it. I tried by keystrokes (KeyPress) but all is bad.

This is my code:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Lines[1];
        }

        private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void aboutToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("KNit-11-1  Zavalinich I.D");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide code that is not working and I am pretty sure that you will find an helpful answer

Comment: We cannot really help you there, your question really doesn't let us know what problem you have. Could you try and be more specific so we  can help?

Comment: Is it Windows forms or WPF or...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [`TextChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.textchanged(v=vs.95).aspx) event that you can hook into and then simply assign the text from the textbox to the richedit

Answer (score 0):

You can write JS code on `onblur` of textbox, and that will take that value and put into `RichTextBox`, but this way , you will not get that data while typing in textbox, basically it will work when you gets out of `TextBox` .